# HTML tags from database showing in fixed div

Tags: php, html, mysqli, pagination, longtext

I have a div where i display formatted text from database and there is also pagination when the number of characters that i want to display in the div are used up. However, there are times that the html tags are being displayed also. I think i must detect html tags and make them not break when the max characters are used up. How can  fix this?

I used part of http://coursesweb.net/php-mysql/pagination-class-script_s2 for paginating content

```
// method to split the text into number of characters (specified in the $txtchr property) without breaking words


  public function getText($text) {

    // if the $txtpieces higher than 0, divide the $text into a number of pieces specified in $txtpieces
    // otherwise, split the text according to the number of characters specified in $txtchr property
    if($this->txtpieces>0) {
      $this->txtchr = ceil(strlen($text) / $this->txtpieces);    // set $txtchr (length of text piece) according to number of pieces
    }

    // split the text and create an Array with string pieces. Returns the content for the current page
    $newtext = wordwrap($text, $this->txtchr, '#|#');
    $ar_text = explode('#|#', $newtext);
    $nr_pieces = count($ar_text);

    // if paginate by number of pieces, and too many pieces - merge the last two pieces
    if($this->txtpieces>0 && $nr_pieces>$this->txtpieces) {
      $ar_text[$nr_pieces-2] .= ' '. $ar_text[$nr_pieces-1];
      unset($ar_text[$nr_pieces-1]);
    }

    $this->totalpages = count($ar_text);       // sets the number of total pages
    if($this->idpage > $this->totalpages) $this->idpage = $this->totalpages;

    // sets a string to be added at the end of the text content, if not the last page.
    $end = ($this->idpage+1)<$this->totalpages ? ' ...[<i> Continue to next page</i>].' : '';

    return $ar_text[$this->idpage]. $end;
  }

  // method that sets the links
  public function getLinks() {
  $re_links = '';         // the variable that will contein the links and will be returned
  $currentpage = $this->idpage + 1;         // because the page index starts from 0, adds 1 to set the current page
  $pag_get = '?pg=';      // the name for the GET value added in URL

  // if $totalpages>0 and totalpages higher or equal to $currentpage
  if($this->totalpages>0 && $this->totalpages >= $currentpage) {
    // linksto first and previous page, if it isn't the first page
    if ($currentpage > 1) {
      // show << for link to 1st page
      $re_links .= ' <a href="'. $this->pag. '" title="Link 1">First &lt;&lt;</a> &nbsp; ';  

      $prevpage = $currentpage - 1;          // the number of the previous page
      // show < for link to previous page, if higher then 1
      if($prevpage>1) $re_links .= ' <a href="'. $this->pag. $pag_get. $prevpage. '" title="Link '. $prevpage. '">Previous &lt;</a> &nbsp;';
    }

    // sets the links in the range of the current page
    for($x = ($currentpage - $this->range); $x <= ($currentpage + $this->range); $x++) {  
      // if it's a number between 0 and last page
      if (($x > 0) && ($x <= $this->totalpages)) {
        // if it's the number of current page, show the number without link, otherwise add link
        if ($x == $currentpage) $re_links .= ' [<b>'. $x. '</b>] ';
        else $re_links .= ' <a href="'. $this->pag. $pag_get. $x. '" title="Link '. $x. '">'. $x. '</a> ';  
      }
    }

    // If the current page is not final, adds link to next and last page
    if ($currentpage != $this->totalpages) {
      $nextpage = $currentpage + 1;
      // show > for next page (if higher then $this->range and less then totalpages)
      if($nextpage>$this->range && $nextpage<$this->totalpages) $re_links .= '&nbsp; <a href="'. $this->pag. $pag_get. $nextpage. '" title="Link '. $nextpage. '">&gt; Next</a> ';
      //  show >> for last page, if higher than $this->range
      if($this->totalpages>$this->range) $re_links .= ' &nbsp; <a href="'. $this->pag. $pag_get. $this->totalpages. '" title="Link '. $this->totalpages. '">&gt;&gt; Last ('. $this->totalpages. ')</a> ';
    }
  }

  // adds all links into a DIV and return it
  if(strlen($re_links)>1) $re_links = '<div class="linkspg">'. $re_links. '</div>';
  return $re_links;
  }
```

and in my php file

```
// create object instance of the class
$objPg = new Pagination();

// change the number of characters for the piece of text content
$objPg->txtchr = 600;
```

inside my html

```
<div id="left2"><?php echo "<center><b><i>$story_title</b></i> Chapter $chapter_no<b><i> $chapter_title</i></b></center>";?>
        <div id = "ellipsis"><?php // output /display the conntent
        echo $objPg->getText($chapter_content);
   // output / display pagination links
           echo $objPg->getLinks($story_id); ?></div>
        </div>
```

I got this output for the first page

```
This is 6 (24) pt. No other format.



**This is 6 (24) pt. In bold.** 



*This is 6 (24) pt. In italic format.*



This is 6 (24) pt. In underline manner.

Continue to next page].

[1] 2
```

but when i click [2] to display the next text, i got this

```
style="font-size: x-large;">***This is 7 (36) pt. In bold, italic and underlined format.***




First <<   1 [2]
```

i already tried html_entity_decode but the result is the same, what should i do?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: have you tried htmlentities?

Comment: it shows the content from the database which has all the html tags

Comment: what about `html_entity_decode(htmlentities($yourvar))` ? seems like some of the tags are being overlooked somewhere

Comment: it works when i use it without the pagination, but i need to paginate it. I try using this echo $objPg-> getText(html_entity_decode(htmlentities($chapter_content))); but the result is the same

Comment: i think my problem is the pagination. so i will decoded the html tags first and look for a way to fit the decoded html into a div and make pagination